# How can i add + symbol between figures?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm working on a homework right now and I'm stuck with something.So:

```
    a = "32"
    for j in a:
        print(j, sep=" + ", end=" ")
```

This code outputs:

```
      3 2
```

But I want it to print

```
    3 + 2
```

Where do i do wrong ?

Comment: No need for a loop. Just use `*`: `print(*a, sep=" + ", end=" ")`

Comment: also: `print(' + '.join('32'))` `print('{0} + {1}'.format(*'32'))`